# Null integer value without print anything vb.net

Tags: null, integer

I have a problem with this kind of value.

I use WebServices Classes and I cant modify, they are like this..

```vb
Public ClientReference As String

Public Passenger1_Salutation As String
Public Passenger1_FamilyName As String
Public Passenger1_FirstName As String
Public Passenger1_PassengerType As String
Public Passenger1_PassengerAge As Integer

Public Passenger2_Salutation As String
Public Passenger2_FamilyName As String
Public Passenger2_FirstName As String
Public Passenger2_PassengerType As String
Public Passenger2_PassengerAge As Integer
```

And follow until `Passenger12` (with his five attributes)

If i use only two passsengers to send, by default string values are empty (without xml tag) but integer value if it dont have a value, print a 0, that is a value for me. And I dont want a value to dont create any tag if is empty or 0.

My class creates this one..

```xml
  <ClientReference>9124983</ClientReference>
  <Passenger1_Salutation>MR/S</Passenger1_Salutation>
  <Passenger1_FamilyName>TestAp11</Passenger1_FamilyName>
  <Passenger1_FirstName>Test11</Passenger1_FirstName>
  <Passenger1_PassengerType>AD</Passenger1_PassengerType>
  <Passenger1_PassengerAge>30</Passenger1_PassengerAge>
  <Passenger2_Salutation>MR/S</Passenger2_Salutation>
  <Passenger2_FamilyName>TestAp12</Passenger2_FamilyName>
  <Passenger2_FirstName>Test12</Passenger2_FirstName>
  <Passenger2_PassengerType>CH</Passenger2_PassengerType>
  <Passenger2_PassengerAge>10</Passenger2_PassengerAge>
  <Passenger3_PassengerAge>0</Passenger3_PassengerAge>
  <Passenger4_PassengerAge>0</Passenger4_PassengerAge>
  <Passenger5_PassengerAge>0</Passenger5_PassengerAge>
  <Passenger6_PassengerAge>0</Passenger6_PassengerAge>
  <Passenger7_PassengerAge>0</Passenger7_PassengerAge>
  <Passenger8_PassengerAge>0</Passenger8_PassengerAge>
  <Passenger9_PassengerAge>0</Passenger9_PassengerAge>
  <Passenger10_PassengerAge>0</Passenger10_PassengerAge>
  <Passenger11_PassengerAge>0</Passenger11_PassengerAge>
  <Passenger12_PassengerAge>0</Passenger12_PassengerAge>
```

But I need to know how can I do to dont instantiate the integer attributes to xml should be like this (without modify the class, I could put this attribute as string, but cant modify it)

```xml
  <ClientReference>9124983</ClientReference>
  <Passenger1_Salutation>MR/S</Passenger1_Salutation>
  <Passenger1_FamilyName>TestAp11</Passenger1_FamilyName>
  <Passenger1_FirstName>Test11</Passenger1_FirstName>
  <Passenger1_PassengerType>AD</Passenger1_PassengerType>
  <Passenger1_PassengerAge>30</Passenger1_PassengerAge>
  <Passenger2_Salutation>MR/S</Passenger2_Salutation>
  <Passenger2_FamilyName>TestAp12</Passenger2_FamilyName>
  <Passenger2_FirstName>Test12</Passenger2_FirstName>
  <Passenger2_PassengerType>CH</Passenger2_PassengerType>
```

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Primitive types (integers, etc) don't have a `null` (`Nothing`) value - an unassigned integer is `0`. However, VB.NET provides `Nullable Types`, which allows primitives to be `Nothing`. Creating them is easy - simply add a `?` to the end of your variable declaration:

```
Public Passenger1_Salutation As String
Public Passenger1_FamilyName As String
Public Passenger1_FirstName As String
Public Passenger1_PassengerType As String
Public Passenger1_PassengerAge As Integer?
```

At this point, before assigned a value, the output of:

```
Console.WriteLine("Passenger1_PassengerAge: " & Passenger1_PassengerAge)
```

Will be:

```
Passenger1_PassengerAge:
```

and *not* `Passenger1_PassengerAge: 0`. You can now safely test for `Passenger1_PassengerAge Is Nothing`.

There are however a couple of pitfalls to be aware of:

### Modifying the value

If you tried this with a normal integer:

```
Dim i As Integer
i += 5
Console.Write(i)
```

The output would be `5`. `i` is initialized as `0`, and then `5` is added - obviously, `0 + 5 = 5`

However, watch what happens with an `Integer?`:

```
Dim i As Integer?
i += 5
Console.Write(i)
```

The output is nothing! Depending on how your compiler is configured, it will either output nothing or fail to compile with an error. This is because when initialized, `i` is initialized as `Nothing`, and *not* `0`: `Nothing + 5 = Nothing`.
If you wanted this to work, you would have to explicity state that `i = 0` first before attempting use it in sums.

### Referencing before assignment

With a normal `Integer`, you can declare it and immediately get its type:

```
Dim i As Integer
Console.Write(i.GetType())
```

Which will output `System.Int32` (which is how an `Integer` is represented internally on 32-bit computers). No problem. However, a bigger problem occurs when attempting the same with `Integer?`:

```
Dim i As Integer?
Console.Write(i.GetType())
```

**Crash!** Your program throws a `NullReferenceException` and dies. Someone can edit me if I'm wrong here, but I believe this is because `Integer?` is internally represented as an object rather than a primitive - and `GetType()` is attempting to get the type of an object that doesn't exist yet, so it crashes.

---

Asides those, `Nullable Types` will solve the problem you're having.

I should point out that your class design seems highly inefficient anyway. Consider writing a `Passenger` class or structure, and replacing your code above entirely with a class that contains a collection of `Passenger`s:

```
Structure Passenger
    Public Passenger_Salutation As String
    Public Passenger_FamilyName As String
    Public Passenger_FirstName As String
    Public Passenger_PassengerType As String
    Public Passenger_PassengerAge As Integer?
End Structure

Class MyClass
    Public Passengers() As Passenger
    'etc
End Class
```

Comment: Hah, didn't realize this question was a year old. Hopefully this'll still come in useful to someone :)